# How to Add "My Cart" on my account navigation in magento2?

Tags: magento2

How to add New "My Cart" links from the  menu on customer account page?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Create `customer_account.xml` in your custom module**

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="mycart">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">checkout/cart</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My Cart</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**If you don't have custom module you need to create `customer_account.xml` in your custom theme**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourtheme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account.xml

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Out these code in your module in these location

FIle Path:
**app/code/Extension/Module/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml**

```
page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <attribute name="class" value="account"/>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="Magento_Customer::account/navigation.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customerdashboard_index_index">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">customerdashboard/index/index</argument>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">My Cart</argument>
                </arguments>
        </block>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

And these code in these file

FIle Path:
**app/code/Extension/Module/view/frontend/layout/index.xml**

```
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Extension\Module\Block\Index\Index" name="index_help" template="Extension_Module::Index.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer> 
 </body>
```